# Did Rachel or any of her friends know about Gunther's crush on her?

Tags: character, analysis, friends

As we all know, Gunther from the coffee house (Central Perk) had a huge crush on Rachel. It was shown in the series very often. He'd do anything for her, and he has a big soft spot for her.

Although it was shown on screen for viewers, was there any indication that Rachel knew about his crush? I think maybe she had some idea that Gunther liked her, but it was never indicated (as far as I see it) that she knew about his crush.

Did Rachel or any other from friends group ever know about Gunther's crush on Rachel?

Comment: Women *always* know

Comment: @BlueMoon93 How can *you* tell?

Comment: Well, I think from the fact that it took Rachel 10 years - and a giveaway from Chandler - to pick up on Ross's feeling, it is apparent that that girl is not the best at reading signals, no?

Comment: THEY WERE ON A- oh wait, sorry, wrong question.

Comment: I don't believe F.R.I.E.N.D.S. was an acronym.  Well, wait, Joey *did* know Nick Fury... It's entirely possible they were a sleeper-cell of S.H.I.E.L.D...

Comment: @Harper I personally know Thor, doesn't make me an avenger.. **P.S** Agreed,  F.R.I.E.N.D.S. wasn't an acronym.

Comment: What about C.H.E.E.S.E., as in Mac and -?

Comment: @TobiaTesan It's wordplay. Remember Joey explained long meaning and he saying it's wonderful coincident and others sarcastically agree with him? It's acronym for something else, not milky cheese.but it's funny because as you said the food- Macaroni and Cheese sounds very same

Answer (score 37):

**Yes, in the series finale, Gunther confesses his love for Rachel.**

She tells him she loves him too but not in the same way and then tells him she'll think of him whenever she's in a café having coffee or when she sees someone "with hair brighter than the sun" and gives him a kiss on the cheek before leaving.

Answer (score 19):

In my opinion the best indication of this (assuming you’re asking about before he outright tells her in the finale) is in “The One with Phoebe’s Rats” (S09E12) when Joey and Chandler start to sing Happy Birthday to Rachel, she says:

> “Shhh don't say that loud, Gunther's gonna want to hug me.”

<sup>transcript: [livesinabox.com](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season9/912rats.htm)</sup>

Of course this does not indicate she knew the vast extent of his love for her, but that she had some idea of his attraction.

Answer (score 5):

Nnnnyes. Rachel thought that Gunther is gay but she knew that he would do anything for her. It was shown for example when he bought inside-out cat from her or when she demanded to give Joey his job back

He also said to Joey that he  watch Rachel all day long and to Emily that Rachel is his girlfriend. during the same storyline he thanked (I think) Ross for marrying Emily and not pushing his relationship with Rachel.

Comment: "Did Rachel know he loved her?" "Nnnyes, Rachel thought that he is gay." ... Which is it? Did she think he loved her, or that he was gay? They seem mutually exclusive.

Comment: Rachel might knew about the crush as her friendly were told by Gunther about it by at the same time she was convinced that he is gay. Those two information could exist at the same time.

Comment: To be fair, Gunther said a lot of things like watching Rachel and liking her in front of her friends, but they never really showed that they "understood" that, as in, next time they see him, they don't show any sign that they know. From their point of view, it could be something not serious or something that "Gunther does".

Answer (score 5):

I guess she might have had a clue. In one of episodes, Gunther and Phoebe kissed (she wanted germs to get sick, so her voice would sound better). After that he decided to confess that fact to her, because he was feeling guilty. He did that in a way like they were couple.

Comment: Season 4 episode 5; [transcript](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season4/405jng.htm). But Rachel is very confused as to why Gunther confessed it to her, so she certainly doesn't know *before* he confesses, and we don't see her work it out on screen.

Comment: Of course. I meant the state after confession.